# Absolute Links Resolving to Current Domain

Tags: html, hyperlink, relative-path, absolute-path

My HTML code has never behaved this way before! I have looked around the internet and here and I can't find an answer to this.

The problem is simple: external links do not go to external webpages and instead become internal links

For example:
If I'm on `http://www.domain.com` where I have an external link

```
<a href="http://www.nasa.gov">National Aeronautics and Space Administration</a>
```

When the link is clicked, instead of going to `www.nasa.gov` or opening a new window for `nasa.gov`, it goes to `http://www.Domain.com/www.nasa.gov`

Why is it doing this?

Comment: Do you have any JS on this page? A typo in a JS file could potentially mess up your links like so. Also, when you're visiting the page in a browser, could you right-click the page and hit View Source, and verify the <a> link exactly matches what you expect? Would you mind copying-pasting that link from View Source into a comment here?

Answer (score 2):

I am certain that your address is missing a `/` in your actual code.

```
<a href="http:/www.nasa.gov/">Test</a>
```

would resolve to `http://www.domain.com/www.nasa.gov/`. Note only **one** slash after the protocol.

Two slashes `//` indicate your address is absolute (external) whilst one slash `/` tells the browser to go to the root directory of the current site to find the address (relative). This is because you *could* change protocol (such as `https:`) and then give a relative address (such as `/path/to/content.html`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Anyone coming later might also want to make sure you have the "http://" in there as well, I had some missing...